# Laravel calls API from another API all on localhost

Tags: api, laravel-5, localhost

I developing 2 APIs with Laravel in differents projects (with differents databases).

Into first API, I have an endpoint with something like this

```php
$user = User::where('email', $request->username)->first();
```

If I use a client rest (like postman or insomnia), passing the username, I get the user.

But if I use the second API to call this endpoint passing the username, I get NULL, although the username is right.

I made this test:

```php
\Log::info(env('DB_DATABASE'));
```

and now I know that when call the first API from the second, the first works with the second api's env variables.
But, why?? And how I can avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35180114/3877879

My temporal solution, on localhost, will be add new variable into *.env* called *DB_DATABASE_LOCAL*. I will add project database in this variable and change it in *config > database.php*.

On production will work, but is posible I change to older values because them would be work too.

Comment: You've really saved my time. Thank you!